# Succinct way to summarize different columns with different functions

Tags: r, dplyr

My question builds on a [similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822672/summarize-different-columns-with-different-functions) by imposing an additional constraint that the name of each variable should appear only once.

Consider a data frame

```
library( tidyverse )
df <- tibble( potentially_long_name_i_dont_want_to_type_twice = 1:10,
              another_annoyingly_long_name = 21:30 )
```

I would like to apply `mean` to the first column and `sum` to the second column, without unnecessarily typing each column name twice.

As the question I linked above shows, `summarize` allows you to do this, but requires that the name of each column appears twice. On the other hand, `summarize_at` allows you to succinctly apply multiple functions to multiple columns, but it does so by calling *all* specified functions on *all* specified columns, instead of doing it in a one-to-one fashion. Is there a way to combine these distinct features of `summarize` and `summarize_at`?

I was able to hack it with `rlang`, but I'm not sure if it's any cleaner than just typing each variable twice:

```
v <- c("potentially_long_name_i_dont_want_to_type_twice",
       "another_annoyingly_long_name")
f <- list(mean,sum)

## Desired output
smrz <- set_names(v) %>% map(sym) %>% map2( f, ~rlang::call2(.y,.x) )
df %>% summarize( !!!smrz )
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#   potentially_long_name_i_dont_want_to_type_twice another_annoyingly_long_name
#                                             <dbl>                        <int>
# 1                                             5.5                          255
```

**EDIT to address some philosophical points**

I don’t think that wanting to avoid the `x=f(x)` idiom is unreasonable. I probably came across a bit overzealous about typing long names, but the real issue is actually having (relatively) long names that are very similar to each other. Examples include nucleotide sequences (e.g., `AGCCAGCGGAAACAGTAAGG`) and [TCGA barcodes](https://docs.gdc.cancer.gov/Encyclopedia/pages/TCGA_Barcode/). Not only is autocomplete of limited utility in such cases, but writing things like `AGCCAGCGGAAACAGTAAGG = sum( AGCCAGCGGAAACAGTAAGG )` introduces unnecessary coupling and increases the risk that the two sides of the assignment might accidentally go out of sync as the code is developed and maintained.

I completely agree with @MrFlick about `dplyr` increasing code readability, but I don’t think that readability should come at the cost of correctness. Functions like `summarize_at` and `mutate_at` are brilliant, because they strike a perfect balance between placing operations next to their operands (clarity) and guaranteeing that the result is written to the correct column (correctness).

By the same token, I feel that the proposed solutions which remove variable mention altogether swing too far in the other direction. While inherently clever -- and I certainly appreciate the extra typing they save -- I think that, by removing the association between functions and variable names, such solutions now rely on proper ordering of variables, which creates its own risks of accidental errors.

In short, I believe that a self-mutating / self-summarizing operation should mention each variable name exactly once.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822672/summarize-different-columns-with-different-functions Keep in mind that one of the great benefits of using dplyr is that it makes your code easier to read. Being this adverse to typing column names seems odd. Are you using Rstudio's autocomplete features? Is this really a problem?

Comment: I agree with @MrFlick, but if you really are that averse to typing the names, you could create the `sym`'s up front from `v` and then just do a regular `summarise()` referring to everything via `!!` and the resulting list of `sym`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose 2 tricks to solve this issue, see the code and some details for both solutions at the bottom :

A function `.at` that returns results for for groups of variables (here only one variable by group) that we can then unsplice, so we benefit from both worlds, `summarize` and `summarize_at` :

```
df %>% summarize(
  !!!.at(vars(potentially_long_name_i_dont_want_to_type_twice), mean),
  !!!.at(vars(another_annoyingly_long_name), sum))

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#     potentially_long_name_i_dont_want_to_type_twice another_annoyingly_long_name
#                                               <dbl>                        <dbl>
#   1                                             5.5                          255
```

An adverb to `summarize`, with a dollar notation shorthand.

```
df %>%
  ..flx$summarize(potentially_long_name_i_dont_want_to_type_twice = ~mean(.),
                  another_annoyingly_long_name = ~sum(.))

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#     potentially_long_name_i_dont_want_to_type_twice another_annoyingly_long_name
#                                               <dbl>                        <int>
#   1                                             5.5                          255
```

---

**code for `.at`**

It has to be used in a pipe because it uses the `.` in the parent environment, messy but it works.

```
.at <- function(.vars, .funs, ...) {
  in_a_piped_fun <- exists(".",parent.frame()) &&
    length(ls(envir=parent.frame(), all.names = TRUE)) == 1
  if (!in_a_piped_fun)
    stop(".at() must be called as an argument to a piped function")
  .tbl <- try(eval.parent(quote(.)))
  dplyr:::manip_at(
    .tbl, .vars, .funs, rlang::enquo(.funs), rlang:::caller_env(),
    .include_group_vars = TRUE, ...)
}
```

I designed it to combine `summarize` and `summarize_at` :

```
df %>% summarize(
  !!!.at(vars(potentially_long_name_i_dont_want_to_type_twice), list(foo=min, bar = max)),
  !!!.at(vars(another_annoyingly_long_name), median))

# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#       foo   bar another_annoyingly_long_name
#     <dbl> <dbl>                        <dbl>
#   1     1    10                         25.5
```

---

**code for `..flx`**

`..flx` outputs a function that replaces its formula arguments such as `a = ~mean(.)` by calls `a = purrr::as_mapper(~mean(.))(a)` before running. Convenient with `summarize` and `mutate` because a column cannot be a formula so there can't be any conflict.

I like to use the dollar notation as a shorthand and to have names starting with `..` so I can name those "tags" (and give them a class `"tag"`) and see them as different objects (still experimenting with this). `..flx(summarize)(...)` will work as well though.

```
..flx <- function(fun){
  function(...){
    mc <- match.call()
    mc[[1]] <- tail(mc[[1]],1)[[1]]
    mc[] <- imap(mc,~if(is.call(.) && identical(.[[1]],quote(`~`))) {
      rlang::expr(purrr::as_mapper(!!.)(!!sym(.y))) 
    } else .)
    eval.parent(mc)
  }
}

class(..flx) <- "tag"

`$.tag` <- function(e1, e2){
  # change original call so x$y, which is `$.tag`(tag=x, data=y), becomes x(y)
  mc <- match.call()
  mc[[1]] <- mc[[2]]
  mc[[2]] <- NULL
  names(mc) <- NULL
  # evaluate it in parent env
  eval.parent(mc)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Moody. I appreciate all the effort you put into this answer. Your adverb / tag system looks quite intriguing. Do you have a package or some text that formalizes this? I'm curious to learn more.

Comment: I think adverbs are underused, the concept of a function returning a function is not trivial, and it also adds brackets. A "tag" (still not sure about the name) is more intuitive, you stick it to your function and it changes its behavior, here by preprocessing the arguments, but it could be a side effect or add an additional argument. Tags allow you to develop in a single function features for many functions, for instance my solution works using `transform` as well. @G-Grothendieck's `gsubfn::fn` is pretty much another example of tag (and the only one I've seen).

Comment: The system is really young and I'm still figuring out, but I'll take this opportunity to formalize it into a package and write a draft doc on the philosophical points this weekend and ping you here.

Comment: Thank you, @Moody. I've been using `purrr::partial` and `purrr::compose` quite extensively (probably more than I care to admit), but I've always felt that all the extra brackets made things messy. I wonder if this would be a great setting for adverbs.

Comment: Definitely, *magrittr*'s functional sequences take all the features from `compose` and `partial` without the brackets, but the pipe symbols are bulky and starting from a `.` is awkward, so I wrapped it into a tag `..fs` and I can do `fun <- ..fs$substr(1,3)$toupper$paste0("-",.); fun("hello")` and it'll return `"-HEL"`

Comment: @ArtemSokolov you'll find my package *tags* there : https://github.com/moodymudskipper/tags along with a readme which showcases the features + some reflections. If you feel like sharing your thoughts about it don't hesitate to open an issue as I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Got it, @Moody_Mudskipper. Lots of interesting ideas there! I'll post my thoughts later today or tomorrow.

Comment: awesome, it is discussed a bit here as well : https://community.rstudio.com/t/classes-attributes-of-functions/28430

Answer (score 2):

Use `.[[i]]` and `!!names(.)[i]:=` to refer to the ith column and its name.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

df %>% summarize(!!names(.)[1] := mean(.[[1]]), !!names(.)[2] := sum(.[[2]]))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  potentially_long_name_i_dont_want_to_type_twice another_annoyingly_long_name
                                            <dbl>                        <int>
1                                             5.5                          255
```

### Update

If df were grouped (it is not in the question so this is not needed) then surround `summarize` with a `do` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(tibble)

df2 <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = 11:20, g = rep(1:2, each = 5))

df2 %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  do(summarize(., !!names(.)[1] := mean(.[[1]]), !!names(.)[2] := sum(.[[2]]))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      g     a     b
  <int> <dbl> <int>
1     1     3    65
2     2     8    90
```

Comment: Note that if the tibble is grouped the  groups will be ignored with this solution

Comment: `df` in the question is not grouped.  Clearly if the problem changes then you need to change the answer appropriately.  In the case of grouped data one needs to surround `summarize` with `do`.  See the Update.

Comment: Indeed, the given example is minimal, the wider issue of using summarize with long variable names though applies frequently to grouped data frames so your edit is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hacky function that uses unexported functions from dplyr so it is not future proof, but you can specify a different summary for each column.

```
summarise_with <- function(.tbl, .funs) {
  funs <- enquo(.funs)
  syms <- syms(tbl_vars(.tbl))
  calls <- dplyr:::as_fun_list(.funs, funs, caller_env())
  stopifnot(length(syms)==length(calls))
  cols <- purrr::map2(calls, syms, ~dplyr:::expr_substitute(.x, quote(.), .y))
  cols <- purrr::set_names(cols, purrr::map_chr(syms, rlang::as_string))
  summarize(.tbl, !!!cols)
}
```

Then you could do

```
df %>% summarise_with(list(mean, sum))
```

and not have to type the column names at all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can use `map2` for this.

```
map2_dfc( df[v], f, ~.y(.x))

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#   potentially_long_name_i_dont_want_to_type_twice another_annoyingly_long_name
#                                             <dbl>                        <int>
# 1                                             5.5                          255
```

Comment: Thanks, @IceCreamToucan. Minor suggestion: changing the order of the arguments to `map2` will preserve the names and remove the need for subsequent `set_names()`: `map2_dfc( df[v], f, ~.y(.x) )`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, changed