# Merging multiple rows per group into one while merging only some column data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a set of rows and columns of data of posts and comments on Reddit where a row represents a post and it's comment. Since one post could contain multiple comments, I have rows with the same id (post id) and different comment ids. I want to merge the rows with the same id for one row and have all the different comment ids in the column - 'comment id' separated by commas. But also since the post data (title, body etc.) are duplicated (as shown in the attached image), I don't need them merged as only one occurrence per row.

![duplicate rows][1]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0O2t.jpg)

I could merge the comment information for relevant columns separated by commas but I don't know how to get the one occurrence of the duplicated post information which does not need merging.

```
all_reddits <- all_posts_and_comments %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(
    comment_id = paste(comment_id, collapse=","),
    comment_author = paste(comment_author, collapse = ","),
    comment_body = paste(comment_body, collapse = ","),
    comment_score = paste(comment_score, collapse = ","),
    comment_created_date = paste(comment_created_date, collapse = ","),
    comment_link = paste(comment_link, collapse=",")
  )
```

I have tried summarise_all() and summarise_at() of R: dplyr but I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just use a summary statement like `post_datapoint_xyz = first(post_datapoint_xyz)` for each of the *post*-columns to address your problem.

What also works would be to simply include all the *post* columns into your `group_by` list :)
// update: you can do this quickly by writing it as

```
all_reddits <- all_posts_and_comments %>%
  group_by_at(vars(starts_with('post_'))) %>%
  summarise(...)
```

`summarise_all` or `summarise_at` won't get you far here, as you want to apply two different functions (paste & first) to two different groups of variables (comments & posts) and the two `summarise_*` functions don't support that.
There's a bunch of suggestions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822672/summarize-different-columns-with-different-functions), but those might be overkill for your use-case...

---

However, on a side note: you might not be doing yourself a big favor by just concatenating each comment column individually, as you're losing the relation between them in doing so.
(imagine one of the comments containing a comma, you wouldn't be able to reverse this summary.)

If you really want to retain the full comment data in your result, you could consider creating only *one* summary column of all the comments where you store them as a list or nested df.

// update: if you want to do this, you can use [the nest function](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html) like so:

```
all_reddits <- all_posts_and_comments %>%
  nest(starts_with('comment_'), .key = 'comments')
```

If you desire to unnest these comments later, the `unnest` function can help.

```
all_posts_and_comments.2 <- all_reddits %>%
  unnest(comments)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and it works, I get the output as I wanted. Also with regard to the second point you've mentioned, yes is true! But can you please provide me with an example as to how to do it? I'm a newbie to R and couldn't find what you are saying.

Comment: Hey Nez, happy to hear that. I've added two updates to my answer to help you get going there :)   
My general suggestion would be to split the data up into one dataframe containing the post information and a separate dataframe containing the comments with a reference to the post_id, but if you really want to have all in one, then the `nest` function should do the trick for you.