# Summarize different Columns with different Functions with dplyr in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have seen this ([Summarize different Columns with different Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822672/summarize-different-columns-with-different-functions))

But in my situation, I want to use `sum()` with `mpg`, `disp` and `hp`. And use `mean()` with  `drat`, `wt` and `qsec`.

All the function should be used with a group variable `cyl`.

Like this:

```
result.1 = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(across(.cols = c(mpg, disp, hp),
                                              .fns = sum))


result.2 = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(across(.cols = c(drat:qsec),
                                              .fns = mean))

final.result = full_join(result.1, result.2)
```

Is this possible that get `final.result` only use `summarise()` once.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `across` twice in the same `summarise` call :

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(across(.cols = c(mpg, disp, hp),.fns = sum), 
            across(.cols = c(drat:qsec),.fns = mean))

#    cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4  293. 1156.   909  4.07  2.29  19.1
#2     6  138. 1283.   856  3.59  3.12  18.0
#3     8  211. 4943.  2929  3.23  4.00  16.8
```